# Creating Zip Using Foreach in PS Produces Nothing

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a little use case where I need to zip each directory within a directory (the subdirs are flat, so no worry about recursion) and attempting to do so with a simple one liner in PS has produced nothing I can even debug with. That said, I'm very green when it comes to Powershell.

Here's what I'm using currently to no avail:

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory
foreach($directory in $directories) { Compress-Archive -Path $directory.FullName -DestinationPath "$($directory.FullName).zip" }
```

The console briefly flashes suggesting the command to zip ran, but there is no output - I'm just trying to write to the same directory where the target dirs are located. I've sanity checked to see if I'm using the right attribute on the Object, and the foreach loop for that produces what I'd expect:

```
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Directory
foreach($directory in $directories) { echo $directory.FullName }
```

As another sanity test, I created a series of dummy dirs with a single small file within that follow a simple scheme incrementing a suffixed integer. ex.: test1, test2, etc. and did a similar test but with a for loop:

```
for($num = 1; $num -le 3; $num++) { Compress-Archive ".\test$num\" "test$num.zip" }
```

Which does correctly produce zips from the test dirs. I'm baffled as to why foreach looping over the result of get the `Get-ChildItem` call isn't well-received by `Compress-Archive` when I can verify it does iterate over each directory.

Comment: `Compress-Archive` does not create a compressed archive, or zipped file, if directory specified by `-Path` is empty. Please check `tree.com . /F`.

Comment: Thanks for noting this! I figured out what was wrong. I needed to use `-LiteralPath` on Compress-Archive instead of `-Path`

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my particular use case was that `Compress-Archive` needed to use the `-LiteralPath` argument rather than the `-Path` argument.